# Ionic can't find firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I've started a sample application using Ionic, and I started integrating Firebase Auth. For now, my application contains a single page show a login/password form.
The integration seems to work properly, I can check if the user is authenticated and retrieve the user profile. However, my issue here is that after a little of testing, maybe after 10 minutes, or generally after another `ionic serve`, the following is returned :

```
Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'firebase'.
src/app/app.component.ts
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.form.value.email,  this.form.value.password).catch(function(error) {
```

Things might work again the next hour or so. Or after a complete reboot.

**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.1/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyBiCVLhPuyfLV6qXI01IeTR_fcDs-dJoBY",
      authDomain: "racer-c6f75.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://racer-c6f75.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "racer-c6f75",
      storageBucket: "racer-c6f75.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "1070195339797"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.ts :**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;
  form : FormGroup;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [''],
      password: ['']
    });

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  signInWithEmail(){
    console.log("XXXXX");
    console.dir(this.form.value);
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.form.value.email,  this.form.value.password).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorCode);
      console.log(errorMessage);

      // ...
    });
    console.log("YYY");
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      console.dir(user);
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
    }
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts :**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any idea ? I've tried wit AngularFire with similar results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//first, download firebase with "npm install --save firebase"

// in app.components.ts
`Import firebase from 'firebase/app';`


// initialize your app with firebase details in app.modules.ts

`var app = firebase.initializeApp({
apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>',
messagingSenderId: '<your-sender-id>'
});`
```

Answer (score 1):

> Typescript Error: Cannot find name 'firebase'.

## Hotfix

Create `globals.d.ts` and add `declare var firebase:any`

## Better fix

Don't include firebase in `script` and use the npm module that comes *with* typescript definitions. More : https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web

```
npm install firebase
```

Comment: Better fix did it. Would you please explain what are typescript definitions and why they are needed (and not shipped in the js library file )? What does the declare var firebase:any exactly means ?